# Do we only allow questions written in English?

Tags: discussion

Based off of [como evitar que pgadmin III se desconecte de postgresql cada 15 minutos aproximadamente?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204842/como-evitar-que-pgadmin-iii-se-desconecte-de-postgresql-cada-15-minutos-aproxima)

Would you vote to close? Ask to be translated? Let it stay?

Comment: Я думаю, ответ напрашивается сам собой.

Answer (score 11):

For me, the best course of action seems to be **leaving a comment** explaining that the question should be in English ***and* voting to close** as unclear.

Of course, if you know the language, you could try translating the question to English, assuming you have enough time and desire to do that. But there is no guarantee the OP will be able to understand the answers. Or to leave useful feedback if need be.

And I am not even touching on such issues as whether the translation is going to be accurate or whether the question is articulate enough to begin with.

Just don't bother. The comment will tell the OP and the audience what is wrong with the post, and closing the question will ensure automatic cleanup in case the OP just abandons it.

See also: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: Couple that with the typical urge to go use translation software, it could only make matters worse.

Answer (score -2):

https://espanol.dba.stackexchange.com comes up blank.

And if we made separate forums for each language, they would all try to get into the english speaking one, anyways.

Why should SQL people be required to exchange information in English?

Granted, if you can't read a question in Spanish, you can't answer it, but maybe, somewhere there is a person who can read Spanish and answer the question.